# Fixed menu bounce, infinite scroll, pagination

Tags: jquery, css, pagination, infinite-scroll

I have made a paginated infinite scroll site, on which I want to have a fixed menu. It all works well except that the menu 'bounces' when the page reaches the top or bottom (which is normal with most browsers).
Is it possible to remove the bounce from the menu, while keeping it in tact for the rest of the page? 
[This](http://luukschroder.nl/Scrolltest/index.html) is the website.

I am fixing the menu like this:

```
.menu {
position:fixed;
top:50px;
left:20px;
}
```

The jquery script works with document height and push content.
I have used the script from this page if anyone is interested: 
https://github.com/rakuishi/jquery-infinite-scroll

Comment: Viewing your site on Chrome 59 - no bounce for me...

Comment: interesting... i have chrome 59 as well and it bounces, same in safari...

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 if that helps?